# uintmax_t for vector indexes

Tags: c++, vector, indexing, bit-fields

I am dealing with basically a bit-flag search mask and I'm using vectors.  These indexes need to go up to the max integer on the machine (defined in stdint.h)

Basically the problem is

```
searchMask[ UINTMAX_MAX] = false; // or any value > unsigned int
```

results in the following warning

```
warning: C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'uintmax_t' to 'unsigned int', 
possible loss of data
```

I have considered just using something like an `unsigned char* = "1110010..."` and just flipping the bits that way, but dealing with C-strings is always a pain and I suspect accessing the char array index will have this same size problem?

Can I make the indexes of the `vector` go off the `uintmax_t`, or should I go the C string route, or what?

Comment: You have a vector of `UINTMAX_MAX` elements _in memory_?

Comment: But that must have gotten you into trouble at a much earlier point, e.g. when running `resize()` or whatever you did to make it larger..?

Comment: The call to resize is what alerted me to this warning.

Comment: I am afraid you just can't have a vector that large -- it would be larger than your (virtual) memory anyway. Vector indices use `std::size_t`, which apparently is `unsigned int` on your system. `uintmax_t` is a larger data type on your system. There is no way you can use that.

Comment: Also, `UINTMAX_MAX` is a synonym for `UINT64_MAX`. If you're on a 32-bit system, this is larger than `size_t`.

Comment: @anthony-arnold Why did you delete your answer? I was just going to upvote it.

Comment: @jogojapan A bit trigger-happy. The whole answer is kind of moot, seeing as having an array that big is brain-damaged. Anyway, I put it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically all the STL containers will use `size_t` as their size types. So, depending on your system, `size_t` might be defined as an `unsigned int`, which will probably be a 32-bit integer in your case. That would explain why the compiler is complaining.

`UINTMAX_MAX` is defined as `UINT64_MAX`, so it won't fit in a 32-bit integer. Try using the `UINT32_MAX` macro, or be platform-independant and use `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.

Also, try using [`std::bitset<N>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/).